# glEnableClientState is not need for glVertexPointer in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am developing in android 2.1 framework.

According to Opengles's doc, we should call **glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)** to make glVertexPointer used by glDrawElements. But I didn't see that from my tutorial, could anybody tells my why, any clue?

My tutorial is: 
I try to create a 3d application that display a simple cube, I found that whether I use

1. glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
2. glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
   //glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

It makes nothing different of result, a cube was displayed normally.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, if you'll use the several cubes, one with color array and another without color array, you'll need to disable (GL_COLOR_ARRAY) color array before drawing a cube without color array